# Array map function is not working (not rendering elements in React)

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, arrow-functions

How can I `map` over array to display all elements from that array?

When I try to render single entry it works but when I map an array it doesn't do anything.

**Below Works:**

```
<h1>{thisSeries[0].productColor}</h1>;
```

**Below does not work:**

```
{thisSeries.map((el) => {
  <h1>PRODUCT: {el.productColor}</h1>;
})}
```

I have another `map` in the same render over the same array **that works**:

```
<div>
  {thisSeries.length >= 0 &&
    thisSeries.map((el) => (
      <Link
        key={el._id}
        className="link"
        to={`/pr/add/ph/m/p/variant/${el._id}`}
      >
        <button
          style={{ width: "80%" }}
          onClick="window.location.reload();"
        >
          {el.title}
        </button>
      </Link>
    ))}
</div>
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! why is it though if there is an arrow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Array#map` method creates a new array populated with the results (i.e. **return value**) of calling a provided function (i.e. **callback**) on every element in the calling array.

Here are different ways you can use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

1. A named function as callback:

```
const data = [1,2,3]
data.map(function foo(d) {
  return d*d
})
```

2. An anonymous function as callback:

```
const data = [1,2,3]
data.map(function (d) {
  return d*d
})
```

3. An arrow function (using `{}`) as callback:

```
const data = [1,2,3]
data.map((d) => {
  return d*d
})
```

4. An arrow function as callback:

```
const data = [1,2,3]
data.map((d) => (d*d))
```

5. An arrow function (without `{}` or `()`) as callback:

```
const data = [1,2,3]
data.map((d) => d*d)
```

---

Check [Traditional functions vs Arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#comparing_traditional_functions_to_arrow_functions).