# can not map array inside of object

Tags: arrays, reactjs

I am lost here, can not find a way how to map through an array that is inside of object. I have received an object from API that includes an array wit values like this:

```
{
    "shelters": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Útulok pre psov - TEZAS"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "OZ Tuláčik Brezno"
        }
    ]
}
```

now I need to iterate through the array that is inside and take action on every item to populate the DOM.

my code is:

```
render() {
        // const { isPending, shelters} = this.props;
        if (this.props.isPending === false) {
            var listOfShelters = this.props.shelters;
            console.log('loaded', typeof(listOfShelters), listOfShelters)
            return (
                <div>
                    <select style={this.selector} name="útulky" onChange={this.sendId}>
                    { listOfShelters.shelters.map(function(shelter, i) {
                        <option id={shelter.id}>{shelter.name}</option>
                    })}
                    </select>
                </div>
            )
        } else if (this.props.isPending === true) {
            console.log('fetching')
            return (
                <select style={this.selector} name="útulky" onChange={this.sendId}>
                    <option id='0'> Nahravam Data... </option>
                </select>
        )}
    }
```

I get `typeof` always an object even if I do `this.props.shelters.shelters` which should be direct access to that array. if I do `this.props.shelters.shelters.map` nothing happens, my list of shelters does not get populated. it stays empty. Where do I make the mistake here?

Comment: Try `return <option .....` See [Array map function is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66519768/2873538)

Comment: Can you show the code of the parent component handling the shelters state passed down as props? When props change value the component rerenders, so your problem might be in the parent component

Comment: Plus console.logging the type of: `const arr = []` returns you "object" as an array is actually an object. If you want to check if an array is an actual array, then use `Array.isArray(arr)` instead

Comment: you should log listOfShelters or use debug tools to see the content

Comment: What is that console log printing?

Comment: When props change the array updates fine, I have a logger that shows succesfull fetch and assigns it to the array. I also get `console.log` from the if statement so it gets to there as well. I also thought that it will always show an object in the console since array is also an object. I will try some of your suggestions to test for actual array.

Answer (score 0):

I have found what the problem was. I had different set of parentheses in the .map function, I was using `{}` instead of `()`. Now it works like a dream.