# Don't understand why a variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This little function uses tt (an array of test objects) and is expected to return a coherent array of objects like `[{ testNum: [e, e, e, e] }, ...]` where "e" is an empty array element.

```
  buildValues = tt => {
    tt.map( aTest => {
      const tn = aTest.testNum;
      return { tn: new Array( aTest.items.length )};
    })
  };
```

The linter gives a warning in the `const` line:
`TestsPane.js|93 col 13 warning| 'tn' is assigned a value but never used. (no-unused-vars)`
And effectively the `return` line does not use tn as I expected.
What am I doing wrong?

Below, a simplified element of the `tt` array:

```
  let tt = [
    { testNum: 1,
      items: [ { value: 0 },  { value: 1 },  { value: 0 }, { value: 0 } ]
    },
  ...
```

I've tried this in nodejs and it effectively fails as the linter suggests.

THE SOLUTION, built on top of the great answers I got:

```
  buildValues = tt => tt.map( aTest => {
      return { [aTest.testNum]: new Array( aTest.items.length )};
  });
```

Comment: Please add a example of `tt`. We need a [mre]!

Comment: you even never return the result of `map`. please add what you want as result.

Comment: `const tn` and `{ tn: ... }` are two separate things and they're not related to each other. the first one is a variable name and the second one is an object's key. So it's normal that the linter is giving you that warning.

Comment: You may want to see this post - [How to use map](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66519768/2873538)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241875/how-to-create-an-object-property-from-a-variable-value-in-javascript

Comment: `tn` in the return object is not the same as the const declared outside it. The error basically says that you are declaring `tn` with `aTest.testNum`, but you are not using it for anything.

Comment: may be you need the `tn` to be the returned object `key`
so that would be something like this: `return {[tn] : new Array( aTest.items.length )}`

Comment: Thanks to all who answered or commented.  
I learned how to code an object's key dinamicaliy: the key expression has to be enclosed in brackets for JS to consider it a reference, not a literal.

Comment: Also, my code example shed additional confusion because I omitted the `return` when I edited my original one-liner that leveraged the implicit arrow-functions return for simple cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you wanted it to be like so:

```
buildValues = tt => tt.map( aTest => {
    const tn = aTest.testNum;
    return { [tn]: new Array( aTest.items.length )};
});
```

Comment: Initially I wanted to be like this:  
`tt.map( aTest => ({ aTest.testNum: new Array( aTest.items.length )})`  
a single liner, but the linter compleined of the dot
I'll try it with your brackets.

Comment: it would work like this: tt.map( aTest => ({ [aTest.testNum]: new Array( aTest.items.length )})

Answer (score 2):

Indeed you are not using the variable tn.
You return an object with the key "tn" and not the value of the variable tn.

```
const tn = aTest.testNum;
const myValue = {};
myValue[tn] = new Array( aTest.items.length );
return myValue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
items: [ { value: 0 }.  { value: 1 }.  { value: 0 }.  { value: 0 } ]
```

You should be separating them with a comma.

```
return { tn: new Array( aTest.items.length )};
```

If you have a dynamic key you should put them in brackets like this

```
return { [tn]: new Array( aTest.items.length )};
```

Comment: Yes @Marko, the dots instead of commas are a typo, I already fixed it to avoid confusion.   
And yes, the midding brackets seem to be my issue.